# If $\mu(X)<\infty$, $\int |f_n|<C$ for all n, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.Show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $\mu(X)<\infty$, $\int |f_n|<C$ for all n, and $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.Show that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.

I tried to use uniform integrability but I could not figure out completely.

Does  conditions $\int |f_n|<C$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$ imply also  $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Perhaps you have misread the hypothesis, and instead of $\int |f_n| < C$ it should just be $|f_n| < C$?  Then this would be a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: No originally the question was there exist a C>0 such that $\int f_n^2<C$ holds for all n. But then I applied C-S to get $\int |f_n|<C_1$ then tried to prove under this assumption which was wrong start as seen at below by counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $X=[0,1],f_n=2^n\cdot1_{[2^{-n},2^{-n+1})},f=0$.

Also, [Egorov's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov's_theorem) gives you convergence in probability (almost sure convergence is stronger than convergence in probability in probability spaces).

In case $\int |f_n|^2d\mu < C$, observe that we can employ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to obtain
$$
\int _E |f_n|d\mu \leq \mu(E)^{1/2} C^{1/2}.
$$
for any set $E$. In particular
$$
\int |f_n-f|d\mu\leq \int_{E^c} |f_n-f| d\mu + \mu(E)^{1/2}C^{1/2} + \int_E |f|d\mu.
$$
Now use Egorov's Theorem to pick an appropriate set $E$.

Comment: In the original question, it was $\int f_n^2<C$ which implies also $\int |fn|<C$ by C-S inequality. But in this case, your counteraxmple also works by setting $f_n=2^{n/2}...$

Comment: I could not find a counter example if the condition $\int f_n^2<C$ holds instead of  $\int |f_n|<C$. It might be true under the condition $\int f_n^2<C$. Any suggestion, thanks in advance